# bash script permissions listing

Tags: bash

I want to find the permissions (777) for a directory recursively in a bash script.  This is only finding directories permissions and not files.  Any help appreciated.

```
#!/bin/bash
x=777
dir=/dir
perms=$(stat -c %a $dir)

if [[ $perms = $x ]]; then
find $dir -type d -perm $x  > list

fi

if [[ $perms = $x ]]; then
find $dir -type f -perm $x  >> list

fi
```

Comment: Why are you using `find -type d` if you don't want to restrict to directories?

Comment: I don't necessarily want to restrict it but I can't get it working with or without type...

Comment: Do you actually have files whose permissions are exactly 0777 octal?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is actually what you are after?

```
find . -exec stat {} \+
```

Comment: GNU `find` has various extensions which allow you to look for particular permission combos.

Answer (score 1):

This command should help: `find . -type d -perm 777` (replace `.` with your starting directory). The `-type d` part makes sure only directories and not regular files are found.